# 2013 Elantra hatchback gauge cluster issues

Tags: hyundai, electronics, gauges

recently on a rather cold day I started my car in order to commute to work, I then noticed the complete lack of speedometer and the fuel gauge is all over the place. Engine temp gauge and tachometer are fully functional as well as the electronic shift indicator. The odometer has also stopped working. Unfortunately I'm not well versed in dealing with electronic faults and have absolutely 0 idea as to why only some of my gauges would just suddenly stop. The car is also not throwing back any error lights which is extra confusing. I have absolutely no idea what could potentially be wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did anything change after the car was completely warmed up? You had no problems starting the vehicle?

Comment: The vehicle started perfectly fine and nothing changed when it had reached operating temp.

Comment: Whenever I see funky stuff like that, I usually will start looking for ground faults somewhere ... which are probably the hardest thing to realize. No fun at all to track down and prove its the issue.